# Why can't I make this type generic? Type "x" cannot be used to index type "y" ts(2536)

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write a generic type which takes a root-level property name and returns a union type of a property nested underneath it. For example:

```
interface operations {
  updateSomething: {
    "201": {
      schema: number;
    };
    "400": {
      schema: string;
    };
  };
}
```

If I want to get the "schemas" for the type `updateSomething`, it should resolve to `number | string`. The non-generic version works fine:

```
type UpdateSomethingSchema =
  operations["updateSomething"][keyof operations["updateSomething"]]["schema"];

// string | number ✓
```

My attempt at writing a generic type is:

```
type SchemaOf<
  O extends keyof operations
> = operations[O][keyof operations[O]]["schema"];
```

But this gives me an error:

```
Type '"schema"' cannot be used to index type 'operations[O][keyof operations[O]]'.ts(2536)
```

Interestingly, if I ignore the error, the type does seem to work:

```
type UpdateSomethingSchema = SchemaOf<"updateSomething">;

// string | number ✓
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a limitation of TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it with help of distributive conditional types:

```js
type Schema<T> = {
  schema: T
}


interface operations {
  updateSomething: {
    "201": Schema<number>;
    "400": Schema<string>;
  };
}

type SchemaOf<
  O extends keyof operations
  > = operations[O][keyof operations[O]] extends Schema<infer S> ? S : never

type Result = SchemaOf<'updateSomething'> // string | number
```

IF `operations[O][keyof operations[O]]` infers to object with `schema` property, TypeScript is able to infer the type of `schema: T` and because of distributivity, it will return a union type.

[Distributive conditional types docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I found I was able to achieve the same without `infer` just by doing:

`T extends { schema: any } ? T["schema"] : never`

But in some cases the `infer` approach is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why TS can't figure it out on its own, but it doubts that "schema" is one of the keys of that object, fortunately with a little bit of encouragement it works:

```
type SchemaOf<O extends keyof operations> = operations[O][keyof operations[O]]["schema" & (keyof operations[O][keyof operations[O]])];
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This helped me a lot, I think I have to choose the other answer as the correct one though as it is slightly more detailed.