# Extract values from deeply nested object structure

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a deeply nested object structure that contains other objects that all should have a `value` key, I'm trying to keep the object structure and replace the values with the type of values for each key. Now I've created a type `Result` that almost does what I need it to do, however, the created type also has an error.

`T[key]['value']` - `Type '"value"' cannot be used to index type 'T[key]'.(2536)`

I'm also struggling with how to do it that if the `value` prop does not exist, it defaults to `string`

```
class A<T = string>{
    constructor(public value:T){}
}

const data = {
    propA: {value:'test'},
    nested:{
        propA: new A([123]),
        propBool: new A(123)
    }
}


type Replace<T, A extends {value:any}={value:any}> = T extends object
    ? { [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends {value:any}? T[key]['value'] : Replace<T[key], A> }
    : T;


type Result = Replace<typeof data> //ok

class A<T = string>{
    constructor(public value:T){}
}

const data = {
    propA: {value:'test'},
    nested:{
        propA: new A([123]),
        propBool: new A(123)
    }
}


type Replace<T, A extends {value:any}={value:any}> = T extends object
    ? { [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends {value:any}? T[key]['value'] : Replace<T[key], A> }
    : T;


type Result = Replace<typeof data>

// result
type Result = {
    propA: string;
    nested: {
        propA: number[];
        propBool: number;
    };
}
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCA8AVaBeaEAuAnAlgOwHMA+AbwChpLpgB7PTLAV2AxqwAoAHRgIxB2DQAbmBCMApgC5EAShIBfMorK16GaABMwGMKmjkq0TlhqdYk-SLFSA5BnGYb8gDQUqeB-Y2SDhqsdNzaA8Adzh2AG0ARgAmAGYAXRlXP38TTgAhGhoQC1Dw2LiZN0pFZTIMAE9OcWgAJXFOcGBxJGc4aHEAD3s8DRgSKwlJMDxK+RRB0WHR8aI9ZG7e-ugaHgArcRYS6AB+fWgIgGtxSuh8aBPKmgAzaEQEi0Rj04TOnvE+gaGpWfl955XBIRGw-GxvCwNJpgFpIF6VBLtWDzRSGJ4AbjIWKqNXqDkYIHUaChzVaOPEt002jA8wA9LSaEcyEA)

Comment: This looks exactly the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67240685/why-cant-i-make-this-type-generic-type-x-cannot-be-used-to-index-type-y-ts, so you can do the same thing - `T[key]['value' & keyof T[key]]`

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova Can you post this as the answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an intersection type to affirm that`value` is one of the fields of `T[key]`: `T[key]['value' & keyof T[key]]`